# Send javascript multidimensional array via ajax post

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax, send

I have a multi-dimensional array like below

```
var myarray = new Array();
myarray["firstkey"] = new Array();
myarray["firstkey"]["secondkey"] = new Array();
myarray["firstkey"]["secondkey"]["0"] = new Array();
myarray["firstkey"]["secondkey"]["0"]["a"] = 100;
myarray["firstkey"]["secondkey"]["0"]["b"] = 1200;
myarray["firstkey"]["secondkey"]["0"]["c"] = 32000;
myarray["firstkey"]["secondkey"]["0"]["d"] = 23001;
myarray["firstkey"]["secondkey"]["0"]["e"] = "text";
myarray["firstkey"]["secondkey"]["0"]["f"] = "text";
myarray["firstkey"]["secondkey"]["0"]["g"] = "text";
myarray["firstkey"]["secondkey"]["0"]["h"] = "";
myarray["firstkey"]["secondkey"]["0"]["i"] = 0;
myarray["firstkey"]["secondkey"]["0"]["aa"] = new Array();
myarray["firstkey"]["secondkey"]["0"]["bb"]["bbb"] = 16;
myarray["firstkey"]["secondkey"]["0"]["cc"]["ccc"] = "text";
myarray["firstkey"]["secondkey"]["0"]["dd"]["ddd"] = new Array();
myarray["firstkey"]["secondkey"]["0"]["ee"]["eee"]["0"] = "text";
myarray["firstkey"]["secondkey"]["0"]["ff"]["fff"]["1"] = "text";`
```

and I want to get it from PHP, but I can't find solution. Can anybody please tell me the solution. The response would be highly appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean "__I want to get it from php__"?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try sending JSON?

You should read it from PHP with:

```
$json = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

Comment: when i send it through ajax it shows me the [] and in the php $_POST is showing Array()

Comment: True. When you send just JSON with POST to PHP, $_POST comes empty. Then you receive the request body with `$json = file_get_contents("php://input");`. Then you can decode it with `json_decode()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do AJAX

**The JavaScript:**

```
var array = JSON.stringify(myarray);
$.ajax({
    url: "/myphp/file.php",
    data: {array: array},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        alert(data["return"]);
    }
});
```

**The PHP:**

```
$array = json_decode($_POST["array"]);
$savedVal = $array["firstkey"]["secondkey"]["0"]["a"];
echo json_encode(array("return" => $savedVal));
```

Comment: First thanks for the answer but when i send it form your way, the array in post shows me blank and i can not get at php untill the data should be post, in case of multidimensional array which keys is like string it always gives me blank.

Comment: Did you get it my problem?

Comment: JSON stringify routines may ignore the string keys properties and only serialise the numerically indexed properties.Did you try it own?